# Hide "public" folder in direct access

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, public

I already have my .htaccess in my root folder with this structure:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And everything works fine, I have my URL "http://example.com" clean without the public folder. But if I access like "http://www.example.com/public/" in the URL the "public" still there, how can I hide it when I access in this way?

If I make a redirection this provoque an infinite loop.

Comment: No rewrite rule is necessary. You need to put the project outside of "public_html" folder and create a symbolic link that point to Laravel public folder.

Comment: No need to rewrite .htaccess,put public directory as root

Comment: This is a shared hosting and I can't put the project in the level above, so all the files and folders are inside public_html. If I don't rewrite, I have to always write "public" in the URL to access the project.

Comment: Ask your hosting company if they can point the domain to your `public` folder or move to different hosting.